# Where is the dominated convergence theorem being used?

Tags: time-series, covariance, autocorrelation, stationarity

I am trying to fully understand the proof of a theorem, I only have a problem with the application of the dominated convergence theorem. For the sake of completeness I will upload the whole statement and proof:

[image]

I focus only on the second part, the proof states:

[image]

And If $ \sum_{h = -\infty}^{\infty} |\gamma(h)| < \infty$ then the dominated convergence theorem gives:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n Var(\bar{X_n}) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{|h| < n} \Big( 1 - \frac{|h|}{n} \Big) \gamma(h) = \sum_{h = -\infty}^{\infty} |\gamma(h)| $$

I understand the proof up until the dominated convergence theorem is used, do we not need a Lebesgue integral to use it? And what are we using it on?

Comment: Hint: Since the left hand side of the inequality is proportional to the variance of a random variable, where in the definition of the variance might an integral be involved?

Comment: Thanks! So $nVar(\bar{X_n}) = n E (\bar{X_n} - \mu)^2$ and the integral comes form here, but we have a function that dominates the whole integral ($\sum_{h = -\infty}^{\infty} |\gamma(h)|$) and not only the pdf.  Looking at the wikipedia article for the dominated convergence theorem I am talking about the $g$ function. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem.

Comment: @whuber Is this a dominated converge for sums?

Comment: I think that's the intention.  The sum is, after all, a Lebesgue integral with respect to a counting measure supported on the natural numbers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

\begin{align*}
 n \text{Var}(\bar{X}_n) 
&=  n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \text{Cov}(X_i,X_j) \\
&=  n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \gamma(i-j) \\
&= n^{-1} \sum_{h = -(n-1)}^{n-1} (n-|h|) \gamma(h) \\
&=  \sum_{h = -(n-1)}^{n-1} \left( 1-\frac{|h|}{n}\right) \gamma(h) \\
&=  \sum_{h \in \mathbb{Z}} f_n(h) 
\end{align*}

where $f_n(h) := \mathbb{I}(|h| < n)\left( 1-\frac{|h|}{n}\right) \gamma(h)$. Notice that

1. $f_n \le |\gamma|$ pointwise for any $n$, and
2. $|\gamma|$ is "integrable" because it's the same as absolute summability in this case (i.e. $\sum_{h=-\infty}^{\infty}|\gamma(h)| < \infty$).

Taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ on everything and applying DCT gives us

$$
\lim_n \sum_{h \in \mathbb{Z}} f_n(h) = \sum_{h \in \mathbb{Z}} \gamma(h)
$$

because $f_n \to \gamma$ pointwise as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Nice answer. For the second point, that $\lvert \gamma(h)\rvert$ is "integrable", you mean that the (right, left or other) Riemann sum of this converges to its Riemann integral, which must be bounded by hypothesis? In this case, some continuity conditions must be imposed to the function $\gamma$, right?

Comment: Most of this algebra is invalid because the sums, as written, diverge.  That's why the expression in the question sums over values of $h$ less than $n$ in size and then takes the limit.

Comment: @whuber see edits

Comment: That works better, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One way to think about the dominated convergence theorem is that it is one of those theorems that give sufficient conditions for *when you can move a limit inside an infinite sum or integral*.  In this answer, I will give a slight variation in the explanation in the other answer, to frame things in this way.  This is really the same thing that the other answer is showing, but it is re-expressed here in a way that may be more familiar to readers who think of the dominated convergence theorem in the way I have described it here.

As shown in the other answer here, you can write the relevant quantity of interest as:

$$n \mathbb{V}(\bar{X}_n) = \sum_{h \in \mathbb{Z}} f_n(h) 
\quad \quad \quad f_n(h) \equiv \mathbb{I}(|h| < n) \bigg( 1 - \frac{|h|}{n} \bigg) \gamma(h).$$

We also have the limiting function:

$$f(h) \equiv \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(h) = \gamma(h).$$

Now, if we are allowed to move the limit inside the infinite sum then we would have:

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \mathbb{V}(\bar{X}_n) 
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{h \in \mathbb{Z}} f_n(h) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{h \in \mathbb{Z}} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(h) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{h \in \mathbb{Z}} f(h) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{h \in \mathbb{Z}} \gamma(h). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

What allows us to move the limit inside the infinite sum here (which is essentially an implicit interchange of limits) is the [discrete version of the dominated convergence theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585319/).  This says that we can move the limit inside the sum if $|f_n(h)| \leqslant f(h)$ for all $h \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\sum_{h \in \mathbb{Z}} f(h) < \infty$.  The first of these conditions clearly holds in this case.  The proof you are looking at is saying that if $\sum_{h \in \mathbb{Z}} |\gamma(h)| < \infty$ then the latter condition also holds and so we can then apply the dominated convergence theorem to get the require result.